# PWA with splash screen on Android (Chrome) fails to display special characters in app name

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I'm writing a Progressive Web App.

Here is my manifest :

```
{
  "short_name": "MyShortName",
  "name": "MyLongNameWithASpecialCharEAcute\u00e9",
  "background_color": "#d2edef",
  "display" : "standalone",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/img/icons/android-48x48.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "48x48"
    }, .....
```

In Chrome Android, the banner is well displayed to propose to install the web app on the homescreen.
But then when I launch the app from the homescreen, the splash screen displays the name and icon, but the é (\u00e9) is replaced by a question mark error character.
Am I missing something?
Is it a bug of Chrome Android?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you specify the encoding? Maybe it is somewhere not set to UTF-8